# How to set image url in anchor tag data value

Tags: laravel, image, anchor

I am working on a laravel project.My table shows some value and if i click eye icon to view then more details of that table shows in the modal.But i don't know how to pass the image source in anchor tag data value.

```
@foreach ($employees as $employee)
            <tr class="post{{$employee->id}}">
                <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->bank->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->bankbranch->location}}</td>
                <td><img alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="70" src="{{url('images',$employee->image)}}"/></td>
                <td>{{ $employee->created_at}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm"  data-id="{{$employee->id}}" data-bank_id="{{$employee->bank->name}}" data-bankbranch_id="{{$employee->bankbranch->location}}" data-salary="{{$employee->salary}}" data-qincentive="{{$employee->qincentive}}" data-fbonus="{{$employee->fbonus}}" data-hrent="{{$employee->hrent}}" data-ename="{{$employee->ename}}" data-ephone="{{$employee->ephone}}" data-relationship="{{$employee->relationship}}" data-gender="{{$employee->gender}}" data-religion="{{$employee->religion}}" data-bgroup="{{$employee->bgroup}}" data-mstatus="{{$employee->mstatus}}"  data-transportallowance="{{$employee->transportallowance}}" data-eaddress="{{$employee->eaddress}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                </a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your src to `src=“{{$employee->image}}”` providing the image url is stored in that variable. If not then you’ll need to do concatenation like `src=“{{‘/images/’ . {{$employee->image}}”`

Comment: i have to pass the image in <a> tag data value like i passed all the data.How do i do that?

Comment: The image itself or just the url to the image? If it's just the url I'm assuming you do the same thing for all the others. `data-image="{{$employee->image}}"`

Comment: So parse `$employee->image` and reference it on the modal where you want the image to be like you've done with everything else?

Comment: Could you post the code to the modal? Where you’re trying to get it to show?